# Start using something by October 26th, is that "by" "no later than" or from?

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence "Start using something by October 26th", is the word "by" understood as "no later than" or from that date?

Thanks

Comment: I would understand it to mean "No later than"

Comment: I second the duplicate, voting to close. Especially since the questioner has the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

**By** appears to be a flexible term and we may need more information of the wording around it or what it refers to. However the word **start** implies it would begin *on/before* that date.

In the meantime, see if it is close to any of the dictionary entries below: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/by

(9)

a 
: not later than (a specified time) : at, in, on, or before (a specified time)

```
We need to leave by noon at the latest.
They should be here by tomorrow.
I don't know where she is. She should have been back by now.
By this time next year she hopes to have a new job.
She's planning to get married next year, by which time she hopes to have a new job.
```

b 
: during the time until (a specified time)

```
By 2000 the U.S. had been an independent country for more than 200 years.
```

Answer (score 0):

The word means 'no later than' in this sentence. It is being used in a very specific sense.

See the following definition:

## by

> 9 : not later than (a specified time) : at, in, on, or before (a
> specified time)
>
> ```
> We need to leave by noon at the latest.
> They should be here by tomorrow.
> I don't know where she is. She should have been back by now.
> ```

[see learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/by)

If you have to start using something 'by' a given date, once that date has elapsed you should have started using it. This is different 'from' a given date, because I could use my inheritance 'from' the date at which I receive it, but this does not imply I 'have to' or that I 'should' use it from this date. By in this sense, certainly has the idea of necessity attached to it.

Your first suggestion was correct: "no later than".

The word is used in a similar fashion on produce that has to be used no later than a certain date in the UK. These products will be stamped with "Use by: xx/xx/xx" where the xx/xx/xx represents some date by which the product must be used to avoid the risk of eating food that is no longer fit for consumption according to the manufacturer.